# Обработка ошибки чтения XML файла (проверить, пуст ли файл)

Tags: c#, xml

есть метод:

```
public void LoadDataNew()
{
 docXML = new XmlDocument();
        docXML.Load(userPath);
 try
{
//извлекаем данные из xml файла
}
catch (System.Xml.XmlException e) 
 {
                OpenForm(errorHandlingForm);               
                Debug.Log(e);
}
finally { }
```

В общем пытаюсь обработать ошибку XmlException, которая возникает тогда, когда xml-файл содержит ошибки в структуре или вообще ничего не содержит. К примеру, ошибка XmlException появляется и тогда, когда файл, который пытается загрузить пользователь, пуст, т.е. как минимум не содержит ни одного узла, а как максимум вообще может ничего не содержать. Но обработать таким образом ошибку не получается, как правильно ее обработать?

Comment: `Но обработать таким образом ошибку не получается, как правильно ее обработать?` так а какие проблемы то?

Comment: "_как правильно ее обработать?_" Из вопроса не понятно какое поведение от кода вы хотите добиться. Количество возможных вариантов неправильной структуры XML можно создавать до бесконечности. Но в своей сути структура может быть правильной или неправильной. Таким образом, если было выброшено исключение `System.Xml.XmlException` значит структура XML не корректная.

Comment: @mals, хочу, чтобы при возникновении подобной ошибки отработался сценарий в блоке catch. Но так, как я написала (см. код в сообщении), он не отрабатывается, т.е. ничего не происходит при возникновении ошибки XmlException.

Comment: У вам  в примере `docXML.Load(userPath);` находиться в не блока `try`. Это правильно? Файл парситься имено в этот момент.

Comment: @mals да, все отлично парсится, если не вылетает ошибок, к примеру, если не попытаться загрузить пустой xml файл или файл, содержащий ошибки в структуре

Comment: Так поместите `docXML.Load(userPath);` в нуторь `try { }` и тогда будете перехватывать ошибки в `catch (System.Xml.XmlException e) { }`.

Comment: @mals, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить пустой ли файл, как вариант, можно попробовать отрыть файл с XML как обычный текстовый и проверить длину содержимого.

```
using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"D:\1.xml"))
{
    if(fs.ReadToEnd().Trim().Length>0)
    {
        // Файл не пустой
    }
}
```

Что касается структуры XML, то здесь только валидация по схеме (xsd). Пример [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp).

Comment: на самом деле думала над тем, чтобы проверить файл на количество символов внутри него, но отказалась от этой мысли, т.к. файл может быть пуст, может что-то содержать, к примеру, какой-то левый текст. В общем целом, насколько я поняла, когда нарушена структура xml - файла выкидывается ошибка XmlException, а в чем конкретно проблема, неважно: будь то файл пустой, или что-то сдержит. спасибо за ссылку, посмотрю, попробую, если это правильный ответ, отмечу!

Comment: Это плохой способ, имхо. Что если попадётся большой файл в сотни мегабайт? Он весь считается в память только лишь для проверки на пустоту. Потом повторно будет читаться для парсинга xml.